# How to use IF and ELSE statement for sql query

Tags: mysql, sql, if-statement, union

I have query to select for getting answer value. I need to check if it answer or null. I used (d.AM_Answer OR null) it's not working. It taking only null value. So, i have changed my query like below, but it's not working.

```
SELECT a.QM_ID,
       a.QM_QCM_ID,
       a.QM_Question,
       a.QM_Type,
       a.QM_Parent_Id,
       c.AM_Answer,
       c.AM_Comments
FROM question_master a
INNER JOIN Assessment_master c ON (c.AM_QM_ID = a.QM_ID
                                   AND c.AM_HNM_ID = %d
                                   AND c.AM_HM_ID = %d
                                   AND c.AM_ASM_Local_Id = %@)
WHERE a.QM_Parent_Id = 0
  AND a.QM_Status = 'A'
  AND a.QM_QCM_ID = %@
  AND a.QM_QRM_Id = %@ IF(d.AM_Answer IS NULL) THEN
UNION
SELECT b.QM_ID,
       b.QM_QCM_ID,
       b.QM_Question,
       b.QM_Type,
       b.QM_Parent_Id,
       NULL,
       NULL
FROM question_master b
INNER JOIN Assessment_master d ON ((d.AM_QM_ID = b.QM_Parent_Id
                                    OR d.AM_QM_ID = b.QM_ID)
                                   AND d.AM_HNM_ID = %d
                                   AND d.AM_HM_ID = %d
                                   AND d.AM_ASM_Local_Id = %@)
WHERE b.QM_Parent_Id != 0
  AND b.QM_Status = 'A'
  AND b.QM_QCM_ID = %@
  AND b.QM_QRM_Id = %@ ELSE IF(d.AM_Answer IS NOT NULL) THEN
UNION
SELECT b.QM_ID,
       b.QM_QCM_ID,
       b.QM_Question,
       b.QM_Type,
       b.QM_Parent_Id,
       d.AM_Answer,
       d.AM_Comments
FROM question_master b
INNER JOIN Assessment_master d ON ((d.AM_QM_ID = b.QM_Parent_Id
                                    OR d.AM_QM_ID = b.QM_ID)
                                   AND d.AM_HNM_ID = %d
                                   AND d.AM_HM_ID = %d
                                   AND d.AM_ASM_Local_Id = %@)
WHERE b.QM_Parent_Id != 0
  AND b.QM_Status = 'A'
  AND b.QM_QCM_ID = %@
  AND b.QM_QRM_Id = %@ END IF
```

Comment: from http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/working-with-null.html:  You cannot use arithmetic comparison operators such as =, <, or <> to test for NULL.

Comment: @mcalex he can use IS NULL

Comment: i guess it know goves you an error because the union keyword

Comment: what's the difference between the selects in the two cases?

Answer (score 0):

1) To check for nulls, you would use the [COALESCE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce) operator.

2) You can also use SQL CASE statement

3) I would suggest you to use a stored procedure for this as you are preparing a dynamic query

Comment: Can you tell the purpose of each union in your query?

Answer (score 0):

You can put where condition d.answer is not null to select non null answers.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
IF(d.AM_Answer IS null)
```

instead of

```
IF(d.AM_Answer == null)
```